# Bibliography as numbered subsection

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex, sectioning, koma-script

For my Bachelor thesis, I would prefer that the references are listet as a subsection in the section "Appendix"....

The only thing a achieved so far is, that together with \usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind} the Bibliography is listet as a section....but I need it as a subsection.

Another question: Is there any possibility to rename "References"? I would rather want to have "Bibliography" as subsection name...

I used documentclass scrartcl:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Main text}

bla bla bla

\newpage
\section{Appendix}

\newpage 
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} 
\bibliography{Referenzen}

\end{document}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!! Could you post what you've tried (compilable code, please)?

Comment: Yes of course! I put my code into the question

Comment: Off-Topic: If you have a `\newpage` before each `\section` it usually would be a good idea to switch from `scrartcl` to `scrreprt` and use `\chapter` instead of `\newpage` + `\section`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `tocbibind` in combination with the `scrartcl` class. The MWE you posted even generates a warning:

> Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `tocbibind` together
>    with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
>    I'd suggest to use options like `listof=totoc`
>    or `bibliography=totoc`, or commands like
>    `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}` instead of this package,
>    because it breaks several KOMA-Script features of
>    the list of figures, list of tables, bibliography,
>    index and the running head.

In order to get a numbered bibliography, you can therefore add the class option `bibliography=numbered`.

I order to have the bibliography as a subsection of the appendix section, you can use the class option `bibliography=leveldown`.

In order to change the default name of `References` to `Bibliography` you can use `\defcaptionname{english}{\refname}{Bibliography}`.

Here is a complete MWE that incorporated the three suggestions:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=numbered,bibliography=leveldown]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\defcaptionname{english}{\refname}{Bibliography}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Main text}

bla bla bla \cite{key}

\newpage
\section{Appendix}

\newpage 
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} 
\bibliography{\jobname}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Many thanks.

Comment: @GabrielSchmid If it works perfectly, you should [vote for and usually even accept the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).